# How to get the type of route path in Ember

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

If I have in the router map:

```
this.resource('detail', { path: '/detail/:type' }, function() {
    ...
});
```

And I retrive the currentPanth in my Ember Application code:

```
currentPath: '',
ApplicationController : Ember.Controller.extend({
    updateCurrentPath: function() {
        App.set('currentPath', this.get('currentPath'));
        console.log('currentPath',App.currentPath);
    }.observes('currentPath') 
}),
```

When I navigate in my app, I get the route names by console, but when It is "detail" I get "detail.index". How can I get the type?

Comment: what is the `type` for you? the resource name?

Comment: It is a parametre of the path

Answer (score 0):

you only have access to the params in the route, ie. when you are defining your model:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('photo', { path: '/photos/:photo_id' });
});

App.PhotoRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return Ember.$.getJSON('/photos/'+params.photo_id);
  }
});
```

Or you can also use [paramsFor](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_paramsFor), also in the route only.

Depending on what you are trying to acomplish maybe [query params](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/) suit better

Comment: I want to monitorize the url changes. i.e, Centralized monitorizacion from a higth level Route. No monitorizacion in each Route of my app